# Force render format for all actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to respond with json to all formats.

I can force the render format to `json` so the action will render `show.json` despite the `accept` header:

```
  def show
    render formats: :json
  end
```

**How I can set render format for all actions of the controller?**

Something like this:

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  formats :json
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `respond_to do |format| format.html { render formats: :json } format.js { render formats: :json } end` ?

Comment: Check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643738/rails-3-respond-to-default-format

Comment: I don't want to add code to each action so it seems that http://stackoverflow.com/a/6519357/1644531 is only way to handle this?

Comment: if you don't put code into your actions, what are they going to render  in the show action?

Comment: @phoet all actions by default renders the view with its name :\

Comment: @freemanoid so you have json views?

Comment: @phoet as I mentioned in question

Answer (score 9):

As a summary of all comments to the questions and readability for future users, you can do, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643738/rails-3-respond-to-default-format/6519357#6519357):

```
before_filter :default_format_json

def default_format_json
  request.format = "json"
end
```

Comment: Looks good. But are you sure that this is correct? I don't want to change request format, I want to change the format of **response**.

Comment: At least, it works. Up to you to adopt this solution or not :)

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```rb
def my_action
  formats.clear
  formats << :json
end
```

(I've only tested this in Rails 4.2 and 3.2.)

`formats` returns an Array of format symbols. It is delegated to `@_lookup_context`, which is an instance of `ActionView::LookupContext`.

Answer (score -1):

Overwrite the response content type. Read more about the response object here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-response-object

```
before_filter :force_json

def force_json
  response.content_type = Mime[:json]
end
```

**With respond_to:**

```
def action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.any(:html, :js, :json) { render json: @object.to_json }
  end
end
```